# I can't install 'loadR' (climate4R) from github in R

Tags: r

I use Windows 10 and the version of R is 4.0.2. I have tried with Windows and Ubuntu but the problem is the same. Also with other versions of R (3.6.1 and 3.6.3).

The message about the error is as follows:

```
* installing *source* package 'loadeR' ...
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error: package 'climate4R.UDG' 0.1.1 was found, but >= 0.2.0 is required by 'loadeR'
Ejecución interrumpida
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'loadeR'
```

What could be the solution?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling the packages then installing from github appears to overcome this issue. E.g.

```
library(devtools)
install_github(c("SantanderMetGroup/loadeR.java",
                 "SantanderMetGroup/loadeR",
                 "SantanderMetGroup/climate4R.UDG",
                 "SantanderMetGroup/transformeR",
                 "SantanderMetGroup/visualizeR",
                 "SantanderMetGroup/downscaleR"))
```

Comment: That's right, I followed the recommendations that are on github.

Comment: the problem continue

Comment: Did you uninstall everything, then change the order of the packages so that loadeR / loadeR.java were installed first?

Comment: i tried different combinations when installing the packages (in windows and ubuntu), but since there are packages that depend on others, i come back with the original order (your recommended order) and the error is the same

Comment: Which installation instructions did you follow? https://github.com/SantanderMetGroup/loadeR/wiki/Installation ? It might be worth trying the solution listed in this github issue:  https://github.com/SantanderMetGroup/loadeR/issues/42#issuecomment-404874353

Comment: I followed the first link you shared and another one where they show a similar order (if not the same) as the list of packages you published to me. As for the second link, it didn't solve my problem either. Unfortunately.

Comment: I'm sorry @francisco-manquehual, I'm out of ideas - unless someone else can solve the problem the best thing will be to raise an issue on the group's github

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but just in case someone else has the same issue:
It wouldn't install for me either, so I went to:
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk13-downloads.html
and chose the 'Oracle jdk' download and then chose the appropriate Java product to download, then the code below was successful installing:
install.packages(“devtools”)

```
library(devtools)

install_github(c("SantanderMetGroup/loadeR.java",

"SantanderMetGroup/climate4R.UDG",

"SantanderMetGroup/loadeR",

"SantanderMetGroup/transformeR",

"SantanderMetGroup/visualizeR",

"SantanderMetGroup/downscaleR"))
```